# Drop duplicates keeping the row with the highest value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

```
a = [['John', 'Mary', 'John'], [10,22,50]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['Name', 'Count'])
```

Given a data frame like this I want to compare all similar string values of "Name" against the "Count" value to determine the highest. I'm not sure how to do this in a dataframe in Python.

Ex: In the case above the Answer would be:

- Name Count
- Mary 22
- John 50

The lower value John 10 has been dropped (I only want to see the highest value of "Count" based on the same value for "Name").

In SQL it would be something like a Select Case query (wherein I select the Case where Name == Name & Count > Count recursively to determine the highest number. Or a For loop for each name, but as I understand loops in DataFrames is a bad idea due to the nature of the object.

Is there a way to do this with a DF in Python? I could create a new data frame with each variable (one with Only John and then get the highest value (df.value()[:1] or similar. But as I have many hundreds of unique entries that seems like a terrible solution. :D

Comment: You ought to fix your sample input, but my guess is you want `df.groupby('Name').Count.max()`?

Comment: Let me try to fix it, Count.max won't help me here.. I'll try again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Either `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`,

```
df1.sort_values('Count').drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last')

   Name  Count
1  Mary     22
2  John     50
```

Or, like miradulo said, `groupby` and `max`.

```
df1.groupby('Name')['Count'].max().reset_index()

   Name  Count
0  John     50
1  Mary     22
```

Comment: Perfect, I tested this against the larger dataset and it looks like #1 works.

Comment: @Kafka Just curious, why did you think groupby and Count.max would not help?

Comment: it could be my fault for the sample I gave. In my data set I have 7 columns, but most of the value is irrelevant for this effort so I focused on the data types I needed to look at. When I run the Count.max I receive an AssertionError on column count. After I looked through my own code though I made a dumb mistake in the column values. After cleaning it Count.max worked fine.