# Multiple entries in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459651/drop-duplicates-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest-value-in-another-column) to try and apply a solution to my issue. I have a pandas dataframe generated as follows:

```
def sql_query(query):
    import pyodbc as p
    import itertools
    import pandas as pd

    pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
    
    databaseName = 'dbName'
    username = '**************'
    password = '**************'
    server = '**************'
    driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'

    CONNECTION_STRING = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+databaseName+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password

    conn = p.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)

    row = cursor.fetchone()     
    
    desc = cursor.description
    column_names = [col[0] for col in desc]
    data = [dict(zip(column_names, row))  
        for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    conn.close()

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.groupby('Customer')['version'].max().reset_index()
    
    print(df)

sql_query(query)
```

The code outputs the df, but I still find a few duplicates. Any reason as to why tis would happen?
Example output:

Customer      version         date1                        date2

0  |  0112233   |     01 | 2021-01-14 16:00:05.963  | 2020-07-05 21:43:49
1  |  0112234   |     02 | 2021-01-14 16:00:05.963  | 2021-01-12 08:49:56
2  |  0113355   |     08 | 2021-01-14 16:00:05.963  | 2021-01-14 11:27:08
3  |  0113355   |     08 | 2021-01-14 16:00:05.963  | 2021-01-14 11:27:08

I would expect my code to remove one of the lines for customer 0113355, as they have the exact same date.
Any pointers as to why duplicates are not removed, and max value in the column are returned?
08 are the max value, but it should not appear twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `df.groupby('Customer')['version'].max().reset_index()` to `df = df.groupby('Customer')['version'].max().reset_index()`.

Looks like you are creating a view/copy but not overwriting the original `df`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast reply. You're spot on. I totally missed that, and forgot to assign the view to df.

Comment: I also noticed that a duplicate value in date2 caused it to display twice.